# SwiftUI wheel PickerStyle in custom Menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

In SwiftUI, the built in `DatePicker` has two buttons, each of which when clicked displaying a pop up menu with a highly customized view (a calendar, and a multi-component wheel picker respectively).

[image]

**How can I recreate a similar setup but with a custom button and my own wheel style picker in the menu**? For example, I'm trying to create a duration picker in the same style as the DatePicker. Unfortunately, a `Picker` placed inside a `Menu` simply does not render **when rendered with the `.wheel` style**. Alternatives like using the default picker `.menu` style doesn't allow for the same experiences as the setup found in DatePicker. Using a context menu also isn't quite right as it requires a long press and blurs the rest of the screen when open (plus the wheel picker is broken in this view too).

Minimal reproducible example: clicking `Test` does not even open the menu. Note that adding a `.frame(width: 100, height: 100)` or `fixedSize()` to the picker does not help.

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
  @State var selection = 1
  
  var body: some View {
    Menu("Test") {
      Picker("Test", selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
          Text("\($0)").tag($0)
        }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any solutions ?